# jquery post not working and no error

Tags: jquery, forms, post, radio-button

I have a simple radio button that is used to submit data to a script asynchronously using jQuery .post.  When clicking a button the script isn't going past the .post line, and no errors are returned.

```
// this part submits the button click
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('test 1');
      $("input:radio").change(function() {
          alert('test 2');
          $.post('http://google.com/', {'resolution':$(this).val()}, function(data) {
           alert('test 3');
         });
      });
    });
```

The html is here:

```
<input type='radio' id='radio1' name='resolution'   checked/>
<input type='radio' id='radio2' name='resolution'  />
```

There is some extra CSS used to pretty up these radio buttons (making them into a toggle).

The semi-working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrX36/2/).

What is preventing the .post line from working? (I should see a popup with "test 3").

Comment: The callback function will only run if the request was a success. Try using $.ajax() instead, and pass in a error callback.
See docs for guidelines: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The Same Origin Policy is preventing this from working - you cannot make an AJAX request across domains. There are some caveats to that, but nothing that will allow you to scrape Google data from a client side request. To prove this, if you check network traffic from your fiddle, you'll see the request comes back with a `405 Method not allowed`.

Comment: Also, you're trying to select `#resolution` but I don't see an element with an id of `resolution`

Comment: Script lives behind a firewall - used google.come as example - the page it posts to currently echos "hello world" - just one line and no logic.  I've updated the question changing the reference to `#resolution` to `$this`

Comment: Update - permissions on my receiving script were wrong.  Updated perms and the script is now working.  Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why your Ajax post is failing.

1) When I tried to debug your Post using Firebug, it was evident that Google Search (www.google.com) does not accept Post data. An error saying "405 Method not allowed" is returned. That is why your post is not being "successful". So I changed the URL to something like www.imgur.com, or any other URL that accepts post data.

2) For your "Test 3" to appear, the server or the URL you are posting to has to send back some data. If the post is still a success but the server sends empty response, the Alert message "Test 3" is not going to appear. Try to echo something on your server side.

Comment: The script lives behind a firewall so I can't use the exact script.  The actual script is being posted to another php page that outputs "Hello World".

Comment: Try using Ajax. 
      `$.ajax({
              url:"<URL>",
              data:{ resolution: $('#resolution').val()},
              type:"post",
              success:function(data){
              alert("test 3");
              }
          });`

Comment: Permissions were off on the script receiving post data.  Once I updated that, the "test 3" alert box appeared.   Marking your answer technically correct.